# ViewController does not go to Portrait mode even forced

Tags: swift, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` and I display it in `landscape` mode. In some moment this screen opens `Spotify` app to authorize it and automatically opens back our app.

After this moment app needs to go to next view controller in `portrait` mode:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NewPage", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewPage")
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Whatever I do in the next page, it stays in landscape mode. Here what I tried to show it in portrait mode.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear
{
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}

-(void) setOrientationToPortrait
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
    }
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [self updateLayoutsForCurrentOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation view:self.navigationController.view.superview.superview];
}
```

Unfortunately nothing works also `shouldAutorotate` and `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` not even called.

Note: If I press home button in iPhone and get back to the app, portrait mode works.

Comment: May be rotate before pushing? P.S. I have always don't liked undocumented approach with `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];`, for me it's smells like using private API.

Comment: I tried using navigation controller and it worked. Thanks @matt